# Filtering dictionary by values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which I would like to filter if 2 of the value of 2 keys  have each one a defined string

For example, filter (A=BBB and D=EEE) in the the list below...

```
[{A:BBB, C:DDD, D:EEE,...}, {A:BBB, C:DDD, D:ESS,...},{A:BBB, C:ASD, D:EEE,...},{C:ASD, D:EEE,...},...]
```

Would output

```
[{A:BBB, C:DDD, D:EEE,...},{A:BBB, C:ASD, D:EEE,...},...]
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it's a one-liner using list comprehensions:

```
# input data
lst = [{'A':'BBB', 'C':'DDD', 'D':'EEE'},
       {'A':'BBB', 'C':'DDD', 'D':'ESS'},
       {'A':'BBB', 'C':'ASD', 'D':'EEE'},
       {'C':'ASD', 'D':'EEE'}]

# list of filters
flt = [('A', 'BBB'), ('D', 'EEE')]

# a list comprehension + all() will do the trick
[x for x in lst if all(x.get(k, None) == v for k, v in flt)]
=> [{'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'DDD', 'D': 'EEE'}, {'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'ASD', 'D': 'EEE'}]
```

The nice thing of this approach is that you can declare as many key/value pairs as needed in the filter, anyway it'll work.

Comment: This is a far more robust approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for i in lst:
    if i['A'] == "BBB" and i['D'] == "EEE":
        result.append(i)
```

Comment: This will fail if one of the keys is not present in one of the dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'DDD', 'D': 'EEE'}, {'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'DDD', 'D': 'ESS'},
    {'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'ASD', 'D': 'EEE'}, {'C': 'ASD', 'D': 'EEE'}]
filterd = {'D': 'EEE', 'A': 'BBB'}                                         
[x for x in l if x.viewvalues() >= filterd.viewvalues()]                   
[{'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'DDD', 'D': 'EEE'}, {'A': 'BBB', 'C': 'ASD', 'D': 'EEE'}]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
output = [d for d in list_of_dicts
            if not (d['A'] == 'BBB' and d['D'] == 'EEE')]
```

Comment: This will fail if one of the keys is not present in one of the dictionaries

Comment: @ÓscarLópez In this case I have it in all dictionaries... but how would you do if not just for learning?